# Why isn't Eclipse running my Hello World Program?

Tags: java

I have a simple program and when I right click on `file>Run as Java Application`  nothing happens. Here is the program but there are no errors really.

```
public class test1{
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        System.out.println("Testing Testing!");

    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it in Eclipse v3.6 and it runs just fine. Are you sure you're using the correct version or have the plugins to run java apps? Do you have an SDK installed? Are you getting any output in the console tab?

Comment: @canadiancreed o sure, i open perspective and set to Java... But still nothing.. Weird

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the outcome.

Comment: @Shahzeb i would assume a window would pop or something ^__^

Comment: No there is not going to be any popup look at eclipse console. After running go ALT+SHIFT+Q then select option C

Comment: @user1204570 the code you wrote does not make any windows pop up, it writes "Testing Testing!" to the console, make sure the console view is open in eclipse.

Comment: option C being... because i open console and this error pops out # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Comment: :) have you installed JDK on the machine.Do you get the see the console or not.

Comment: I dont think i downloaded the JDK....Can you link me please anyone? @Shahzeb?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/rdara/entry/java_setup_windows or http://java.sun.com/new2java/programming/learn/ or http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+setup+jdk

Comment: Where should i install it? @Shahzeb

Comment: on your machine . I suggest looking at some the youtube tutorials.

Comment: I did and it installed succesfully into C:\Program Files\Java. But my programs isnt working still. @Shahzeb any idea y

Comment: can you compile from dos command prompt using javac now. If not then you have not yet setup your `JAVA_HOME` properly and have not added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to path yet.

Comment: I type in Javac and all this crap comes up which command should i use to compile?

Comment: Is your .java file in a Java Project?

Comment: You can follow the steps here: http://www.javavirtues.com/2013/01/first-java-standalone-application-on.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you checking output window? open Menu--->Window--->Show View-->Console and check

Answer (score 1):

Check the Eclipse console view to see if your output is shown there. If not, check your Problems view for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly likely you don't have your app selected in the package explorer tree at the left.

Just click on the top-most item in the tree (ie. "MyFirstApp") and then try running again. Chances are you had "activity_main.xml" selected as it's the default selection when you built your test app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to see a window then you would be wrong. when you type 
System.out.println("Testing Testing!");     it will put Testing Tesing! in the eclipse console you can know this because of the System part of your code.